# Docpad and openshift

Tags: node.js, openshift, docpad

Has anyone been able to get docpad up and running on [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/) paas? If so, how do you do it? I've configured the port in the environments section of the docpad.coffee file to "process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT" and set the env to "production" - but to no avail. Trying to launch docpad from the server.js file just seems to get the application stuck in a loop of trying to start up and then closing down with an "EACCES" error.

Edit: Here's the error message

```
Error: listen EACCES
at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1003:19)
at listen (net.js:1044:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1110:5)
at startServer (/var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/out/lib/docpad.js:4134:25)
at /var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/out/lib/docpad.js:4204:16
at TaskGroup.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/out/lib/docpad.js:1109:14)
at TaskGroup.g (events.js:175:14)
at TaskGroup.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
at TaskGroup.complete (/var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/event-emitter-grouped/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:556:14)
at TaskGroup.itemCompletionCallback (/var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/event-emitter-grouped/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:347:17)
at TaskGroup.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
at Task.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/event-emitter-grouped/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:405:26)
at Task.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at Task.completionCallback (/var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/event-emitter-grouped/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:128:19)
at DocPad.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/out/lib/docpad.js:922:18)
at ambi (/var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/ambi/out/lib/ambi.js:23:18)
at Task.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/event-emitter-grouped/out/lib/event-emitter-grouped.js:38:23)
at ambi (/var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/ambi/out/lib/ambi.js:23:18)
at fire (/var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/event-emitter-grouped/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:159:23)
at b (domain.js:183:18)
at Domain.run (domain.js:123:23)
at Task.fire (/var/lib/openshift/52deb1644382ec26f9000098/app-root/runtime/repo/node_modules/docpad/node_modules/event-emitter-grouped/node_modules/taskgroup/out/lib/taskgroup.js:166:25)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:317:15)
```

Comment: Can you post that EACCESS error?

Comment: @niharvey - just posted the EACCES error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As niharvey pointed out, we need to tell docpad to listen on a specific address.
In version 6.58 of docpad the "host" option was added to the environments section of the docpad.coffee file. So it needs to have the following section:

```
environments:
    development: 
        # //Always refresh from server
        maxAge: false  # default

        # //Listen to port 9778 on the development environment
        port: 9778
    production: # //this is the important part for openshift

        # //this is the part that open shift needs - 
        # //but its only available in docapd 6.58+
        hostname: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP

        port: process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce this and it boils down to not being able to specify a listening address in the docpad.coffee. I've messaged the maintainers to see what can be done to change that.

Comment: Yes - I was coming to that conclusion too. Will hold off for a bit to see what comes back from the docpad people.

Comment: OK - managed to get it working. The latest version of docpad has got the config option to specify the host - which in openshift's case will be "process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP". I was running 6.53, and the change was implemented in 6.58. The following would be needed in the environments section of the docpad.coffee file: